# Where do I locate Java Servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, solr, lucene

I have installed JRE and now I'm trying to install Solr by following the [Solr Reference Guide](http://servingzone.com/mirrors/apache/lucene/solr/ref-guide/).

The guide dictates:

> 1. Stop your Java servlet container.
> 2. Copy the *solr.war* file from the Solr distribution to the webapps directory of your servlet container...
> 3. Start your servlet container, passing to it the location of your Solr Home in one of these ways:
>
> - Set the Java system property *solr.solr.home* to your Solr
>     Home. (for example, using the example jetty setup: *java
>     -Dsolr.solr.home=/some/dir -jar start.jar*).
> - Configure the servlet container so that a JNDI lookup of *java:comp/env/solr/home* by
>     the Solr webapp will point to your Solr Home.
> - Start the
>     servlet container in the directory containing *./solr*: the default Solr
>     Home is *solr* under the JVM's current working directory
>     (*$CWD/solr*).

Questions:

1. Where do I find this Java Servlet container?
2. Where/how do I execute those commands to start/stop/configure the Java Servlet container?
3. How do I set Java system properties?

Comment: Have you installed a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty?

Comment: I believe I have installed Jetty, it is included in Solr

Answer (score 2):

Mine was quite straight forward. After downloading the file, I extracted it to a folder on  my Server. I used the Command Line to complete the installation.
With the Command line, navigate to the example folder inside the solr-X.XX.X folder you extracted the file to, once there run the java command:

```
cd C:/<folder>/app/solr-X.XX.X/example
    java -jar start.jar
```

It would perform the installation for you, like magic.
You can access SOLR by visiting localhost:8983/solr

I'm using a Windows Server though, it may be different on yours, but I guess the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should to install Apache Tomcat. 
All information about these servers you can find [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/).
You also could to install Jetty, JBoss, vSphere, tc vFabric Server ... but I think that you'll setup tomcat and solr easier (it is mine personal opinion, if you are familiar with any one, use them of course).

Tomcat setup is described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html).

Comment: Before asking this question I had downloaded apache solr and run command _-jar start.jar_. It said that it had started Jetty server and deployed solr successfully. I just wasn't sure how to go about those steps that the guide dictates, such as stop/start/configure Java servlet and set java system properties. Should I go ahead and install Apache Tomcat?

Comment: If you use the standard distribution available from download.eclipse.org/jetty/ you have the start.jar that can be used to start/stop jetty itself. Note that I am not installed solr with Jetty and I didn't follow same tutorial as you are, but you should to stop jetty as it described above. I think that [link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/07/26/jetty-stop-a-jetty-server-by-command/) might be useful for your problem.